# Explain the getline function

Tags: awk

Could any one please explain the getline function in AWK. I've tried going through different websites but couldn't really grasp how exactly it works. Could any one please explain the function with a simple example.

Comment: It's generally excepted that getline usually isn't the best approach  http://awk.info/?tip/getline

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline

Comment: Have a look at my answer here for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773664/perl-how-to-get-lines-between-patterns-in-linux/21778010#21778010

Comment: Make that http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline instead of the awk.info link.

Answer (score 2):

`getline` reads a record of input (yes, `getLINE` is a terrible name for it, `getRECORD` would have been better). It reads it from the currently open file by default, or from a file or pipe you specify otherwise. It is similar to `read` for shell or `gets` for C or any other function you can think of in any other language that reads input. The difference with awk is that awk already reads every line of input for you so `getline` is rarely useful.

Get the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnld Robbins and make sure you read and fully understand all of the caveats discussed at http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline if you're considering using `getline`.